# What kind of lag should I expect when gaming with a KVM?

Tags: usb, dvi, kvm-switch, imac, gaming

I've got an iMac, and am going to get a PC for purely gaming. I'm going to use a KVM to share an external DVI monitor, USB keyboard, and USB mouse between the iMac and the PC.

What kind of lag or other drawbacks should I expect when gaming with this setup? Is there usually a noticeable video delay when gaming in this way?

Comment: The KVM is little more than a passthrough, so you shouldn't see any noticeable latency, unless it's doing some kind of weird on-chip processing or format conversion.

Comment: Okay thanks. Since the PC is purely for gaming, if it doesn't even do that well, then it's pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the KVM for a few years now. There is no lag at all.